# Dá para salvar/pegar informação em cache usando javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, android-manifest

Motivação, tendo uma aplicação offline, é possivel salvar informações em cache e ser enviada assim que o usuario acessar a pagina novamente?

Quanto duraria este cache se possivel? e quais as limitações?

Ps. é usando o manifest do html5

Answer (score 6):

Com o html5 você pode utilizar o localstorage = armazenamento local.

Explicação :

> O que é o armazenamento local em HTML?
>   Com o armazenamento local, as aplicações web podem armazenar dados localmente no navegador do usuário.
>
> Antes do HTML5, os dados do aplicativo deveriam ser armazenados em cookies, incluídos em cada solicitação do servidor. O armazenamento local é mais seguro e grandes quantidades de dados podem ser armazenadas localmente, sem afetar o desempenho do site.
>
> Ao contrário dos cookies, o limite de armazenamento é muito maior (pelo menos 5MB) e as informações nunca são transferidas para o servidor.
>
> O armazenamento local é por origem (por domínio e protocolo). Todas as páginas, de uma origem, podem armazenar e acessar os mesmos dados.

---

Utilizando o locaStorage:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Verificar se existe suporte no browser :

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
// Código localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
// Desculpe! web storage não suportado.
}
```

Comment: obrigado! Salvou meu dia